# Gradle: Как установить главный модуль в много модульном проекте?

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, gradle

Работаю в IntelliJ. Имеется проект:

```
+ Project
++ [Android module]
++ [Java application module]
```

**Settings.gradle**

```
rootProject.name = 'Project'
include "androidmodule"
include "javamodule"
```

**project/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: "java"

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}

sourceSets {
    javamodule {
        java {
            srcDirs 'javamodule'
            exclude "androidmodule"
        }
    }
    androidmodule {
        java {
            srcDirs 'androidmodule'
            include 'javamodule/java/core'
        }
    }
}

compileJava {
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"
}
```

Java module является основным, к немо дописан Андроид модуль, который берет ресурсы из основного проекта.

Проблема: не смотря на то, что Java является основным и таковым должен быть, Main класс определяется будто принадлежит модулю Андроид.

Как сделать так, чтобы основным считался Java модуль, а не Андроид? Да и возможно ли такое?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблему решил установкой плагина [AndroidGradleFacetFix](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/v2/issue/IDEA-122904), который удаляет `facets` из неандроидных проектов.